# Exclude <> from searching tags

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this function that finds the definition of a variable/function in my .emacs file.

```
(defun sm-find-tag-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (find-tag-other-window (funcall (or find-tag-default-function
                         (get major-mode 'find-tag-default-function)
                         'find-tag-default)))
  (recenter 10)
  )
```

However, sometimes on objdump files these functions/variables are enclosed with <> which becomes part of the term I am trying to find the tag for.

Is there a way to exclude these symbols from the tag search using the above function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the tag before finding it, get rid of the <> characters, and then find what's left:

```
(defun sm-find-tag-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((tag (funcall (or find-tag-default-function
                          (get major-mode 'find-tag-default-function)
                          'find-tag-default))))
    (if tag
        (find-tag-other-window
         (replace-regexp-in-string "[<>]" "" (regexp-quote tag))))))
```